# integration of MATLAB output with a C/C++ program in Linux

Tags: c, linux, matlab

I have designed a neural network in MATLAB. I saved the 'net' file which including the structure of the trained network and other required parameters.

Also, I have a program written by C language in Linux (Ubuntu) which generate some data in each second. I want to integrate my 'net' from MATLAB with these generated data. I mean, the 'net' gives each generated data from written program, then print the output based on its training.

How can i integrate a MATLAB program with a written program by C language in Linux?

Comment: So does the C program produce input data for the MATLAB neural network, or is it vice versa?

Comment: Firstly, C program sends input data to MATLAB neural network. Then, MATLAB neural network sends back the result to C program. Then, C program based on the receiving data from MATLAB neural network, will change the way of data generation.

Comment: Are you using the Neural Network Toolbox? Or have you created your own neural network using base MATLAB?

Comment: I used my own coding in MATLAB.

Comment: In which case, you could look into using MATLAB Coder (http://www.mathworks.com.au/products/matlab-coder/), which will turn your MATLAB code into ANSI-compliant C code. You can then import this into your C project directly. However, certain toolbox functions are not supported (http://www.mathworks.com.au/products/matlab-coder/description2.html); hence my earlier question.

Comment: Matlab coder works well, the built in emxutil wrappers provided by Matlab coder wrap up STL containers. Mexfiles are also an option but require you to run your C code inside Matlab. This is easy in theory but gets harder if different C libs are used (they may have their own threading & IO models). Generating platform specific c++/mex code is generally not good practice. For quick and dirty integration during development the Matlab engine is another solution. This allows you to pass Matlab code as strings from your C program (to execute functions calls etc.) and get data back.

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-in-an-ide.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Matlab engine for this task. Basically what I understand is that you need to send data from C/C++ to matlab, run some matlab codes and get a result back to c++.

I have some C++ code for this task.

The Code could be downloaded from https://github.com/thusithaC/CppToMat

Basically using this you can,

1)Open a matlab engine from within a native progam
2) Call whatever matlab functions you want 
3) Transfer data to/from matlab workspace into a native program.

Mind you that the interface might not be super fast. So if you have a fast native program which runs a lot of iterations, calling these matlab routines might slow things up, especially if large data transfers are there. But this utility is mighty useful in debugging stuff, especially if you are first prototyping in matlab and then moving to CPP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your C program to run as part of the same execution as Matlb, you need to use Mex.
http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html

Mex allows your C program to loop just like any other function in Matlab. The "mex" command will compile your program into a shared object that is dynamically linked with Matlab. You need to write a special wrapper aound your C function to unpack arguments from Matlab and pack up the results. Debugging Mex code can be tricky so make sure your C functions are well debugged first.

Comment: I have a simulation (by C program) in linux platform. this simulation run iteratively and gives some results in each second. I am going to send these results as an input value to my MATLAB code. Then, MATLAB code checks the input data and makes a new results and sends back the result to C program. Then, C program based on the receiving data from MATLAB, will change some parameters for new results. This is a looping program until the MATLAB gives an value out of the threshold. Do you think your suggested solution appropriate for my project?

Comment: There are too many unknowns for me judge whether Mex is appropriate. Rather than Mex maybe you can communicate over sockets: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/ . Do you absolutely have to have Matlab? Maybe Python can do the job? I use Matlab because I have a lot of code in Matlab, I interface it to C++ with Mex because I need the speed (and some C++ libraries), but Mex can cause a lot of pain.